# Solve an expression based on user input

Tags: c, logic, expression

I am writing a program that asks the user for 2 inputs: x and y. these values are used to compute this formula: (3x^2-2xy+5)/(y^2+1). When I enter the values --> 2,3 it computes a really small negative number such as -12586511

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int x, y;

    printf("Enter two integer values (x, y): ");
    scanf("%d,%d", &x, &y);

    float E = (3 * (x*x) - 2 * (x*y) + 5) / (y*y+1);

    printf("The expression value is: %.2f\n", E);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "When I enter the values " --> post the exact text of what your entered.

Comment: You are doing integer arithmetic for a start. Because `x` and `y` are `int`s, it will truncate the results of each operation to be integers, which is then assigned to a float.

Comment: check return value of `scanf`.

Comment: @chux that negative number comes from the values

Comment: @chux ....2,3. I edited that in original question

Comment: If it can be read successfully, 5/10 ==> become `0`. problem of the `locale` ?

Answer (score 5):

`-12586511` is certainly the result of invalid data entry.

With input like `"2 3"` or `"2 ,3"` or `"2 , 3"`, `y` will not be set.

```
// Risky code
scanf("%d,%d", &x, &y);
```

Robust code checks the result of `scanf()` to insure proper input.

```
if (scanf("%d,%d", &x, &y) != 2) {
  puts("Error");
  return -1;
}
```

Better to be generous and allow spaces after the number:

```
//           v 
if (scanf("%d ,%d", &x, &y) != 2) {
```

Second issue involves the division being done using `int` math.  OP likely wants the equation to use FP math.

```
// float E = (3 * (x*x) - 2 * (x*y) + 5) / (y*y+1);
float E = (3 * (x*x) - 2 * (x*y) + 5) / (y*y+1.0f);
// or 
float E = (3.0f * (x*x) - 2 * (x*y) + 5) / (y*y+1.0f);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want explicit x,y integers, either you should use MrDonMatti's approach or simply add a dot in front of one of the numbers in Float E expression. for example 3.

```
float E = (3. * (x*x) - 2 * (x*y) + 5) / (y*y+1);
```

This will fix the problem with returning 0 as your result.
**But** the reason of getting a negative value is that you should give x,y to the program exactly like: "2,3". the comma is essential. If you don't use the comma, i.e.: "2 3" as input, it will set y as a not given or I don't know a -nan number that will ruin the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Real fast fix would be something like this:
    `float E = (3 * (x*x) - 2 * (x*y) + 5) / ((float)y*y+1);`
Explanation: promotion of denominator's expression to float value and, finally, whole expression yields float value.

EDIT: as Eisa said, in `scanf()` function all characters except format specifiers should be included in input - in this case `,` is between two integers, so possibilities are:

(whitespaces)first_number(whitespaces),(whitespaces)second_number(whitespaces)ENTER

(...) - optional

Answer (score 0):

While the other posters showed you the possible error, let me add another two cents.

If you mix integer with floating point arithmetic it is a good idea to keep the integer parts isolated as long as possible. It does not make much of a difference here, but you should keep it in mind.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
  int x, y;
  float n, d;
  int res;

  printf("Enter two integer values (x, y): ");
  res = scanf("%d,%d", &x, &y);
  if (res != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "scanf() did not get the expected input\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // keep integer arithmetic as long as possible
  // TODO: check for overflows
  n = (3 * (x * x) - 2 * (x * y) + 5);
  d = (y * y + 1);

  float E = n / d;

  printf("The expression value is: %.10f\n", E);

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

There *are* disadvantages, of course. The most significant is, that the integer parts may overflow where a full floating point calculation would just loose some accuracy. Checking for over/underflows adds some code which is might influence the runtime, too.